# Google Assistant Action Dialogflow integration no longer working

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have several existing Google Assistant Actions projects that are working with an integration with Dialogflow.
In Google Actions for the project the Dialogflow action shows up as,
actions.intent.MAIN

These were created about 12 months ago, so now I am trying to create a new Google Actions project.
I do the following:
https://console.actions.google.com/

- "New Project"
- call it "test"
- select "Custom" next,
- scroll down to the very bottom "Click here to build your Action using DialogFlow"
- gives "Overview" screen
- click "Develop", "Actions", "Add Action"
- "Custom Intent", "Build"
- opens Dialogflow
- save
- setup intents with webhooks
- save

But when I go back to Google Actions I never get the action to show up?

Any ideas? Does Google Actions even work with Dialogflow any more?

Also in trying this on several different accounts I get a wide array of different errors,

- "build" fails to create dialogflow project "com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'test3-cfb28'."
- "build" goes to dialogflow but "sign-in with google" never returns
- reopen dialog flow and get a permissions error

> > update
> > Odd, if I start with Dialogflow and create the Dialogflow project first, then click on its integration with Google Assistant it creates the Google Actions project and correctly links to it.

It seems Google Actions integration with Dialogflow is broken, but Dialogflow's integration with Google Actions works?

Comment: Have you tried creating an agent on Dialogflow first and from there added the Google integration? Google has recently released the action builder sdk, so some creations could be buggy due to this

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work this way. But seems odd that core functionality that use to work is not working the other way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and there definitely is a bug with the integration.

The solution for now seems to create a new Dialogflow agent, go to integrations and click on 'test'. This will integrate Dialogflow with Actions on Google.

If you already have a project, make sure to export the agent and import it at the new project.